# how to handle this array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

There is an array like this:

```
    arr = [
        {id: 1, status: 3},
        {id: 2, status: 5},
        {id: 3, status: 5},
        {id: 4, status: 5},
        {id: 5, status: 5},
    ]
```

In this array, if status of any hash is 3, it will be change to be 2, and others will change to be 1. if each hash status is not 3, the array does not change.

I hope the output should be:

```
    arr = [
        {id: 1, status: 2},
        {id: 2, status: 1},
        {id: 3, status: 1},
        {id: 4, status: 1},
        {id: 5, status: 1},
    ]
```

if the array like this:

```
    arr = [
        {id: 1, status: 2},
        {id: 2, status: 5},
        {id: 3, status: 5},
        {id: 4, status: 5},
        {id: 5, status: 5},
    ]
```

each hash status is not 3, so the array doesn't change.

I can make it like this:

```
    tmp = false
    arr.each do |e|
        if e[:status].to_i == 3
           e[:status] = 2
           tmp = true
           break
        end
    end
    // note: if tmp == false, the array does not change
    if tmp == true
        arr.each do |e|
            e[:status] = 1  if e[:status].to_i == 5
        end
    end
```

But I think it is a bad idea, it will loop two times. Anyone has the better solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so 3 -> 2 and 5 -> 1 ?? or 3 -> 2 and others -> 1 ?

Comment: if 3 exists, 3 -> 2 and others -> 1, if 3 is not exists, the array does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answers submitted only work correctly if the *first* array element is the `status: 3`.

You could do it in a single loop, if you construct a copy of the array as you go, and swap that for the original if you found a match

```
arr = [
        {id: 1, status: 3},
        {id: 2, status: 5},
        {id: 3, status: 5},
        {id: 4, status: 5},
        {id: 5, status: 5},
];


switch = false
new_arr = Array(arr.length)

arr.each_with_index do |e,i|
  if e[:status] == 3
    new_elem = { id: e[:id], status: 3 }
    switch = true
  else
    new_elem = { id: e[:id], status: 1 }
  end
  new_arr[i] = new_elem
end

arr = new_arr if switch
```

So you don't have to iterate the full array twice, but you construct an unused copy array if there is no status: 3.

I think you might want to consider using a different data structure - maybe a specific class that models the state changes you're using. Maybe look at some of the state machine gems.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map do |e|
  new_status = if e[:status] == 3
                 2
               else
                 1
               end
  {id: e[:id], status: new_status}
end
```

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ :) i rolled back. Very ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a ternary:

```
arr.each{|element| element[:status] == 3 ? element[:status] = 2 : element[:status] = 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map do |e|
   {id: e[:id], status: (e[:status]==3) ? 2 : 1}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find_all, twice again but bit cleaner.

```
arr.find_all {|e| e[:status] = 2 if e[:status] == 3  }
arr.find_all {|e| e[:status] = 1 if e[:status] == 5  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid two loops, since you must determine if `arr[i][:status] => 3` for any index `i` before you know whether you need to change the values of `arr[j][:status]` (to `2` or `1`) for all `j`. This is one way you could do that:

```
ndx = arr.index { |h| h[:status] == 3 } #=> 0
if ndx
  arr.each { |h| h[:status] = 1 }
  arr[ndx][:status] = 2
end
arr
```